# Como exibir um arquivo .txt em um JtextArea automaticamente

Tags: java, gui

Eu estou farto de pesquisar e não consigo encontrar como efetuar o display de um ficheiro.txt em um JTextArea automaticamente. Fiz um programa que abre uma janela e logo em seguida queria que ele exibisse o conteúdo desse ficheiro sem ter que carregá-lo em algum botao.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve criar o `JTextArea` **dentro do construtor!**

Segue um exemplo:

> DemoJTextArea.java

```
public class DemoJTextArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Janela jn = new Janela();
        jn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

> Janela.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

class Janela extends JFrame {
    public Janela() {
        super("Display txt on JTextArea!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(250, 250);

        File file = new File("/home/anderson/arquivo.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String texto = "";

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                texto += (char) content;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(texto);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true); //quebra de linha automática
        add(textArea);
    }
}
```

Executando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência: [How To Read File In Java – FileInputStream](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-in-java-fileinputstream/)

Comment: Amigo como posso fazer com que depois de um certo numero de caracteres ou de espaços mude a linha?

Comment: Sim: textArea.setLineWrap(true); Se a resposta foi útil pra você, dê um upvote! Vlw!

Comment: eu acho que ja fiz cara, mas se não ensine me que eu faço voce ajudou me imenso

Comment: Você marcou a resposta como aceita. Porém você ainda pode contribuir com as perguntas e respostas clicando na setinha pra cima caso elas foram úteis. Disponha :)

Comment: ainda nao tenhio pontos de reputacao suficientes -.-

Comment: Precisa de 15 de reputação para poder votar a favor, é um privilégio a ser alcançado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer de uma forma diferente mas que dá o mesmo resultado.

Fiz com que no construtor da tela visual chamasse o procedimento **Leitor();** passando o endereço do arquivo, o leitor lê o que está no arquivo e grava tudo no *ArrayList* **conteudoTxt** que é *public static*.

Voltando ao construtor depois de chamar o leitor passaremos todo o conteúdo do ***ArrayList*** para uma **String** chamada **linha** com a ajuda de um ***for***, em seguida damos um AreaTexto.*setText*(linha); e pronto temos um programa que carrega as informações do arquivo.txt em um AreaText.

Os códigos a baixos estão faltando algumas coisas como *imports* e instanciar para que o programa rode corretamente. Só coloquei o que está em evidência para a solução.

```js
public class JanelaArquivosTxt extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArquivosTxt tela1 = new ArquivosTxt();

    public JanelaArquivosTxt() {
      initComponents();


      leitor("C:\\Users\\Paulo Brito\\Desktop\\paulo.txt");

      String linha = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < conteudoTxt.size(); i++) {

        linha += conteudoTxt.get(i) + "\n";            
      }
      AreaTexto.setText(linha);

    }
    private javax.swing.JTextArea AreaTexto;
}
```

```js
public class ArquivosTxt {

  public static ArrayList < String > conteudoTxt = new ArrayList < String > ();
  private static File arquivo;

  public static void leitor(String path) {

    try {
      BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
      String linha = "";

      if (!arquivo.exists()) {

        arquivo.createNewFile();
      }

      ArrayList < String > linhas = new ArrayList < String > ();

      while (true) {
        linha = buffRead.readLine();
        if (linha != null) {
          linhas.add(linha);

        } else {
          break;
        }
      }

      buffRead.close();

      conteudoTxt = linhas;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(JanelaArquivosTxt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

  }

}
```